# Orientation of figures in space

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d, openframeworks

I have a sphere in my program and I intend to draw some rectangles over at a distance x from the centre of this sphere. The figure looks something below:

[image]

The rectangles are drawn at (x,y,z) points that I have already have in a vector of 3d points.
Let's say the distance x from centre is 10. Notice the orientation of these rectangles and these are tangential to an imaginary sphere of radius 10 (perpendicular to an imaginary line from the centre of sphere to the centre of rectangle)

Currently, I do something like the following:

For n points `vector<vec3f> pointsInSpace` where the rectnagles have to be plotted

```
for(int i=0;i<pointsInSpace.size();++i){
    //draw rectnagle at (x,y,z)
}
```

which does not have this kind of tangential orientation that I am looking for.
It looked to me of applying `roll,pitch,yaw` rotations for each of these rectangles and using quaternions somehow to make them tangential as to what I am looking for.
However, it looked a bit complex to me and I wanted to ask about some better method to do this.

Also, the rectangle in future might change to some other shape, so a kind of generic solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I like your diagram. And your question. Though it's not strictly related to C++, or OpenGL, or "openframeworks", but in fact a mathematics question probably better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you essentially want the same transformation as would be accomplished with a LookAt() function (you want the rectangle to 'look at' the sphere, along a vector from the rectangle's center, to the sphere's origin).

If your rectangle is formed of the points:

```
(-1, -1, 0)
(-1,  1, 0)
( 1, -1, 0)
( 1,  1, 0)
```

Then the rectangle's normal will be pointing along Z. This axis needs to be oriented towards the sphere.

So the normalised vector from your point to the center of the sphere is the Z-axis.

Then you need to define a distinct 'up' vector - (0,1,0) is typical, but you will need to choose a different one in cases where the Z-axis is pointing in the same direction.

The cross of the 'up' and 'z' axes gives the x axis, and then the cross of the 'x' and 'z' axes gives the 'y' axis.

These three axes (x,y,z) directly form a rotation matrix.

This resulting transformation matrix will orient the rectangle appropriately. Either use GL's fixed function pipeline (yuk), in which case you can just use gluLookAt(), or build and use the matrix above in whatever fashion is appropriate in your own code.

Comment: I get a part of the answer but not really sure about how to go by implementing this. If you could write in a bit more detail, that would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Btw, since I have tagged openFrmaeowkrs as well in this question which has a `ofNode` with a `lookAt` function, do you think extending ofNode and drawing figures and further using `lookAt` would eseentially have the same effect?

Comment: I've tried to elaborate on the maths. Yes, generally if your underlying framework has some function for generating a look-at matrix, it would work for this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the answer of **JasonD** is enough. But here is some info of the calculation involved.

Mathematically speaking this is a rather simple problem, What you have is a 2 known vectors. You know the *position vector* and the spheres *normal vector*. Since the square can be rotated arbitrarily along around the vector from center of your sphere you need to define one more vector, the *up vector*. Without defining *up vector* it becomes a impossible solution.

Once you define a up vector vector, the problem becomes simple. Assuming your square is on the XY-plane as **JasonD** suggest above. Then your matrix becomes:

```
up_dot_n_dot_n.X      up_dot_n_dot_n.Y       up_dot_n_dot_n.Z     0
n.X                   n.y                    n.z                  0
up_dot_n.x            up_dot_n.x             up_dot_n.z           0 
p.x                   p.y                    p.z                  1
```

Where n is the normal unit vector of p - center of sphere (which is trivial if sphere is in the center of the coordinate system), up is a arbitrary unit vector vector. The p follows form definition and is the position.

The solution has a bit of a singularity at the up direction of the sphere. An alternate solution is to rotate first 360 around up, the 180 around rotated axis dot up. Produces same thing different approach no singularity problem.